# What is the maximum number of elements allowed in a form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have googled and binged and yahooed this question but can't seem to find an answer. I was working on a form that included over 800 fields but the form's submit function would never execute.  After I pared the form down, the submit function ran.  So now I'm curious if there's an actual built in maximum number of elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, the issue is related to Server configuration, not with Drupal.

There is `max_input_vars` variable in `php.ini` which define the maximum number of variable form elements that can be submitted to a single page.

> The “max_input_vars” setting in the php.ini file is a relatively new
>   option starting last year from PHP 5.3.9. It allows you to control the
>   maximum number of form elements on a page. Some webpages have a large
>   amount of forms/fields for administrative or page configuration
>   purposes. In those cases, we need to increase the number of this value
>   in order to properly view those pages.

There is also `post_max_size` variable in `php.ini`.

> `post_max_size` sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file
>   upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
>   `upload_max_filesize`. If memory limit is enabled by your configure
>   script, `memory_limit` also affects file uploading. Generally speaking,
>   memory_limit should be larger than `post_max_size`. If the size of post data 
>   is greater than `post_max_size`, the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` superglobals are empty.

You can check the [this](http://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/utilize-the-php-ini-file-to-optimize-your-ecommerce-store/) for more details.

Comment: It is worth adding the information about the variable `post_max_size` which worked for older PHP versions too.

Comment: @AjitS, I have edit my answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.  I'm sure I'm hitting one of these limits.  My webhost has set max_input_vars to 5000 and post_max_size to 8M.  I'll live with the smaller form.