# Form $_POST data missing value of submit button

Tags: forms

I have a complex form API managed form that has several fieldsets with nested fieldsets and table elements (defined with webform component editor) with AJAX-controlled 'Add another' and 'Remove Last' buttons. There is also a form submit button at the end of the form, external to all fieldsets.

After a certain (of the order of 100) number of element groups (containing 4 or 5 fields each) are added and the form is submitted, the `$_POST` data generated after submitting the form does not include the value of the input element, so at a later stage the form API cannot determine the correct triggering element in function `_form_button_was_clicked` of form.inc.

The `$form_state['input'][$element['#name']]` element does not exist.

I've doubled the `post_max_data` and explicitly named the input element (by setting `$element['#name']`), all to no avail. I'd appreciate any thought on what else to try...

Comment: Have you checked the max_input_vars issue? See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90638/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-elements-allowed-in-a-form

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you! It would have been nice if php emitted some sort of error or warning under such conditions.

Comment: Usually a warning is emitted in the PHP error log. May be your Drupa isntallation is not configured to whow those PHP warnings, but it should be in the PHP error log.

Answer (score 1):

As [sanzante](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2604/sanzante) suggested, the solution is to increase php's max_input_vars setting. I did it in the site's .htaccess file.