# PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000 and how to fix

Tags: 8, webforms

I have been working on a patch for https://www.drupal.org/project/hubspot for the 8.x version. In fact I found a ticket for this same error for the 7.x version (https://www.drupal.org/project/hubspot/issues/2579147

This occurs when the site has more than a few webforms. This module maps webform fields to fields on hubspot.

The problem is when I submit the form, it includes every field in the form which exceeds 1000 input variables, even when the value is `--donotmap--` as you can see below:

[image]
That is just a small section of values being sent. I think its sitting around 2000 vars being sent.

Trying to figure out a work around for this, but is it even possible to exclude any fields with the value of `--donotmap--` from submitting? I'm pretty sure that is not possible, but that is all I can think of right now. Any ideas besides increasing the `max_input_vars` setting?

**Note**: "[What is the maximum number of elements allowed in a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90638)" is related, but not a Duplicate. My question is how to exlude inputs from submitting, but I believe setting them to disabled will not submit them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum number of elements allowed in a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90638/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-elements-allowed-in-a-form)

Comment: @kenorb yes, related. Duplicate no. My question was how to exlude inputs from submitting, but I believe setting them to disabled will not submit them

Comment: _I believe setting them to disabled will not submit them._ Sounds right, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @clive when writing that answer, I hadn't tried it, but setting them to disabled did work. Unfortunately, it wont be a solution. I'll have to rewrite how all these fields are getting generated.

Answer (score 0):

As for a workaround, you can increase the value of [`max_input_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) variable in your PHP settings.