# View breaks the page output

Tags: 7, views, theming, nodes

Has anyone encountered this problem or can at least help me debug it?

The views is displayed as standard if the parameters are specified.

- *Format:Unformatted list | Settings*
- *Show:Field*

If I change it to *Show:Content | Teaser*, the view is not  displayed. At the same time, in the preview, the results are displayed; if I use `dpm(views_embed_view($name, $display_id))`, then the data is also displayed, but as soon as I display the view on page with `print views_embed_view($name, $display_id)`, not only the view is not displayed; the content of the node and, in principle, the entire content region become empty. If I add a view block in the structure menu to a region on a specific page, then the page simply does not load and an error is displayed in the log.

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0, referer

Comment: Do you increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini ?

Comment: there is no access to the file, but on the same server there is a similar project that uses views, there are no problems with the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum number of elements allowed in a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90638/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-elements-allowed-in-a-form)

Comment: variables was increased, the error disappeared, but the views is still not displayed